# Order results from MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm executing a MongoDB query in ExpressJS via Mongoose.

I have documents that look like the below

```
{
"name": "first",
"spellings": [
"here",
"is",
"you"
],
"keyStageLevel": 4,
"spellingLevel": 2,
"__v": 0
},
{
"name": "second",
"spellings": [
"her",
"is",
"another"
],
"keyStageLevel": 2,
"spellingLevel": 3,
"__v": 0
},
{
"name": "third",
"spellings": [
"snother",
"list"
],
"keyStageLevel": 2,
"spellingLevel": 4,
"__v": 0
}
```

I would like to have the result of my query returned so that
1) the `keyStageLevel` are in order and 
2) within each `keyStageLevel` the `spellingLevel` are shown in order with the details of the document.

```
keyStageLevel 2  
    spellingLevel 3
        name: "second",
        "spellings": [
            "her",
            "is",
            "another"
            ]
    spellingLevel 4
        name: "third",
        "spellings": [
        "snother",
        "list"
        ]
keyStageLevel 4
    spellingLevel 2

    etc
```

My code currently runs
`var spellings = await Spelling.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:{keyStageLevel:"$keyStageLevel",spellingLevel:"$spellingLevel"}}} ]);`

which retuns

```
[
    {
    "_id": {
        "keyStageLevel": 2,
        "spellingLevel": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
        "keyStageLevel": 2,
        "spellingLevel": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
        "keyStageLevel": 5,
        "spellingLevel": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
        "keyStageLevel": 4,
        "spellingLevel": 2
        }
    }
]
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are mostly after is using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to accumulate the remaining document data under each `"keyStageLevel"` this is done using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/). If you want results in specific order then you always need to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), being both before and after feeding to a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage:

```
var spellings = await Spelling.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "keyStageLevel": 1, "spellingLevel": 1 } },
  { "$group" : {
    "_id": { "keyStageLevel": "$keyStageLevel" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
         "spellingLevel": "$spellingLevel",
         "name": "$name",
         "spellings": "$spellings"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

The first [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) ensures the items added via [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) are accumulated in that order, and the final ensures that the "output" is actually sorted in the desired order, as [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will likely not always return the grouped keys in any specific order unless you instruct with such a stage.

This will give you output like:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "keyStageLevel" : 2
        },
        "data" : [
                {
                        "spellingLevel" : 3,
                        "name" : "second",
                        "spellings" : [
                                "her",
                                "is",
                                "another"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "spellingLevel" : 4,
                        "name" : "third",
                        "spellings" : [
                                "snother",
                                "list"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "keyStageLevel" : 4
        },
        "data" : [
                {
                        "spellingLevel" : 2,
                        "name" : "first",
                        "spellings" : [
                                "here",
                                "is",
                                "you"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent reply. I'll try it out after work.